# How to select column by using another column of different table

Tags: mysql

Here is my tables. My Queries is how to fetch a parent phone number if i give particular class. say if i class 10 it should come sachin and dravid parents phone number

```
**Student table**

    Student_name    class   id
    Sachin           10      1
    Dravid           10      2
    Dhoni            5       3
    Kohli            3       4
    Manish           1       5


**Parent_table**

    Parents_phone number    Address     id
    9964289813               Hhk        1
    9611704698               hhk        2
    8722922982               ym         3
    9591237001              Bang        4
    8970893285              dvr         5
```

Comment: Where is the connection between parent and child? You need a parent column in your student table.

Comment: id column is the connection between parent and child

Comment: If id is the join criteria, then write a SQL statement that [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) tables on `id` and share it if you have problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can `JOIN` both the table on `id` column and get the desired data like

```
select pt.Parents_phone_number, 
st.Student_name
from Parent_table pt 
join Student_table st on pt.id = st.id
where st.class = 10;
```

Comment: @DeepChandJaipur, then consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @DeepChandJaipur, click the check button under voting up/down button